# C# XDocument.Parse - Invalid namespace declaration

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm getting an invalid namespace declaration error in some C# code that I'm using inside of an SSIS Script Transformation Component and it has me stumped. The code is as follows:

```
string xml = Row.RejectReason;
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace tns = "http://sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data";
```

When using the above code in SSIS it errors out when trying to parse the XML (possibly because of whitespace), but if I use the same code in a console application it works fine. The only difference being how I declare the value of the xml string:

```
string xml = @"<tns:Event xmlns:tns=""http://sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data""><tns:MaximumSeverity.Code>Error</tns:MaximumSeverity.Code><tns:EventItems><tns:EventItem><tns:Error.Code>MAAS.SUBMIT.REQ.UNAUTHORISEDABN</tns:Error.Code><tns:Severity.Code>Error</tns:Severity.Code><tns:Short.Description>Short desc</tns:Short.Description><tns:Detailed.Description>Detailed desc</tns:Detailed.Description><tns:Parameters></tns:Parameters></tns:EventItem></tns:EventItems></tns:Event>";
```

I've checked the XML string it's trying to pass and I can't see any issue or differences as to why it is failing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to edit the script transformation to add any needed references/namespaces?

Comment: The only reference I added was System.Xml.Linq. Are you referring to my XML namespace?

Comment: I just confirmed it must be an issue with escape characters in the row object presented by SSIS. If I use the same xml string variable from my console app it works without issue, so it must be special characters within the value of Row.RejectReason. Just need to work out how to treat this the same way as I do the string from my console app.

Comment: Maybe, try single quote instead of escaping double quotes i.e. xmlns:tns='http://sbr.gov.au/comn/event.02.data'

Comment: I don't think that'll work. The point is my XML string should be ok but it must contain some escape characters so I need to figure out how to get around that.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to try it.

Comment: That still doesn't seem to work but I might have to try that in a few different ways.

Comment: Ok I've run with your suggestion and it now works if I use a single quote. It just means my solution becomes slightly more complicated. I'll post your suggestion as the answer and maybe someone cab suggest an efficient way of dealing with the double quote. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived column transformation and replace "" with " or '. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation

Comment: This appears to have fixed my issue. I used REPLACE(Field,"\"\"","'") in a derived column transformation that replaces the double double quotes with a single quote. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get around this issue thanks to the suggestion from Hassan above. The issue is that I have a data flow with a csv source, and the last column contains a snippet of XML with error information. The xml namespace in that column is wrapped in double quotes which is causing my parsing issue. If I swap the double quotes for single quotes I can parse the XML.

The question now is how do I swap the double quotes for single quotes within my SSIS package. Maybe someone has a good suggestion?

To get around this for now I'll have to store the XML fragment in a table and modify it from there.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a CSV parser which I'd hope would strip the double quotes automatically.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah it sounds like that might be an option for me. Are there any you can recommend?

Comment: I *think* I've used CsvHelper before, but I can't remember for sure.